# How can I hide all elements in a page except the topmost ancestor of one?

Tags: html, css

I'm writing a test add-on (Firefox) just for learning. At some point it hides all elements but one. I want to do something a little more complicated. My intent is to hide everything but the `<div id ="good">` and necessarily all its ancestor containers.

Here is the sample HTML I'm working on:

```
<section id="wrap">
    <div>...</div>
    <div>...</div>
    <div id="good">...</div>
    <a>...</a>
</section>
```

So I'm trying to add this CSS:

```
body > :not(#good) {
    display: none;
}
```

and of course this is not working, it is hiding everything on the page, I think I need to leave `wrap` from being hidden, but even altering the code, it keeps hiding everything:

```
body > :not([name="wrap"])
```

Comment: Well the parents are not good.... so they are hidden

Comment: There are no elements with a `name` attribute, nor any with the attribute-value of `wrap`; what is it that is “*more complicated*” that you’re trying to do?

Comment: @DavidsaysreinstateMonica in a similar question it pointed out to use name rather than id

Comment: until :has() is supported, there is no much you can do with css

Comment: In this context that advice is definitely wrong, though I’m curious about the situation that led to that being good advice.

Comment: Are you only trying to hide the siblings of the id="good" or all other elements on the page

Comment: @epascarello I want to hide every other tag but id="good" and necessarily its parent container.

Comment: @isherwood the add-on would just add noise, it is out of context, as this is simple CSS, in the add-on I inject the CSS depending on case.

Comment: So you would need to use JavaScript, CSS is not going to do it

Comment: There's no parent/ancestor selector in CSS, so you can't. You'd need JavaScript to find the topmost element in the ancestral tree for `#good` and show that after hiding everything.

Comment: So the best solution is probably to restructure your application logic to avoid the need for that.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to use a child selector(>) for this, instead it should look something like this:

```
section :not(#good) {
    display: none;
}
```

or to target one specific section

```
#wrap :not(#good) {
    display: none;
}
```

Comment: If there are elements inside of good they will be hidden....

Comment: it is not working, it doesn't hide anything outisde `#wrap`